XSL File create SVG Chart with xml data
iam currently trying to convert an xml report to html via an xsl file (works good so far!) and afterwards convert the html to a pdf via xslt-fo.
I'd like to create an svg pie chart with some data from my xml file but iam stucked at getting it to work.
Could anyone tell me what im doing wrong?
My XSL File: (pullout)
<!-- create variables -->
<xsl:variable name="allHits" select="count(//chapter/hit)" />
<xsl:variable name="allCrits" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='critical'])" />
<xsl:variable name="allOK" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='normal'])" />    
<xsl:variable name="allWarning" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='warning'])" />

<svg height="300" width="300" viewBox="0 0 20 20"> 
                    <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="green" />
                    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
                        stroke="tomato"
                        stroke-width="10"
                        stroke-dasharray="calc(50 * 31.42 / 100) 31.42"
                        transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)"
                    />
                    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
                        stroke="yellow"
                        stroke-width="10"
                        stroke-dasharray="calc(50* 31.42 / 100) 31.42"
                        
                    />
                    </svg>




For the record, my variables are conditioned to each other:
allHits = allCrits + allOK + allWarning
This "works" so far that i have a static SVG Pie Chart with 3 slices. But now i'd like to get my viarables into the svg:
<!-- create variables -->
<xsl:variable name="allHits" select="count(//chapter/hit)" />
<xsl:variable name="allCrits" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='critical'])" />
<xsl:variable name="allOK" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='normal'])" />    
<xsl:variable name="allWarning" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='warning'])" />

<svg height="300" width="300" viewBox="0 0 20 20"> 
                    <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="green" />
                    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
                        stroke="tomato"
                        stroke-width="10"
                        stroke-dasharray="calc(<xsl:copy-of select="$allCrits" />* 31.42 / 100) 31.42"
                        transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)"
                    />
                    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
                        stroke="yellow"
                        stroke-width="10"
                        stroke-dasharray="calc( <xsl:copy-of select="$allWarning" /> * 31.42 / 100) 31.42"
                        
                    />
                    </svg>




And now my html Site is just blank. What am i doing wrong? I already accessed the variables using the statement above several times inside my html with no errors.
Thanks in advance!
I already tried several ways to call my variables but with no success

Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

What is calc() doing in the stroke-dasharray? The stroke-dasharray is "A list of comma and/or white space separated s and s that specify the lengths of alternating dashes and gaps." stroke-dasharray | MDN. It is not a CSS property.

You are looking for an attribute value template in the form of stroke-dasharray="calc({$allCrits} * 31.42 / 100) 31.42" in your XSLT code.

The first apparent issue is that you cannot have a CSS function like calc() as a value in the stroke-dasharray attribute. It must be:

A list of comma and/or white space separated s and s that specify the lengths of alternating dashes and gaps. stroke-dasharray

Second, when you use a variable in XSL as a value of an attribute, you either use the shorthand {$variable} or add the attribute using the <xsl:attribute> element.
You would like to create a pie chart made of circle slices with a stroke. That is a good idea. The tricky thing is that you need to be able to calculate the rotation of each slice. Therefore I suggest that you use a named <xsl:template> as a recursive function. I also suggest that you create data as part of the style sheet to represent the structure of your chart. So, here is my version:
XML data:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter>
  <hit class="critical" />
  <hit class="critical" />
  <hit class="normal" />
  <hit class="warning" />
  <hit class="critical" />
  <hit class="normal" />
</chapter>

XSL stylesheet:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:book="http://www.example.org/book"
  exclude-result-prefixes="book">
  
  <xsl:variable name="allHits" select="count(//chapter/hit)" />
  <xsl:variable name="allCrits" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='critical'])" />
  <xsl:variable name="allOK" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='normal'])" />    
  <xsl:variable name="allWarning" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class='warning'])" />
  
  <book:hitcategories>
    <book:cat name="normal" color="green" />
    <book:cat name="warning" color="orange" />
    <book:cat name="critical" color="tomato" />
  </book:hitcategories>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="300" width="300" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <g transform="translate(10 10)">
      <xsl:call-template name="hit">
        <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="0" />
        <xsl:with-param name="elm" select="document('')//book:hitcategories/book:cat[1]" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="hit">
    <xsl:param name="sum" />
    <xsl:param name="elm" />
    <xsl:variable name="catsum" select="count(//chapter/hit[@class=$elm/@name])" />
    <xsl:variable name="totalsum" select="count(//chapter/hit)" />
    <circle r="5" fill="none"
      stroke="{$elm/@color}"
      stroke-width="10"
      stroke-dasharray="{$catsum} {$totalsum}"
      pathLength="{$totalsum}"
      transform="rotate({$sum * 360 div $totalsum})"/>
    <xsl:if test="$elm/following-sibling::book:cat[1]">
      <xsl:call-template name="hit">
        <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $catsum" />
        <xsl:with-param name="elm" select="$elm/following-sibling::book:cat[1]" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

And the resulting SVG:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  height="300" width="300" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <g transform="translate(10 10)">
    <circle r="5" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="10"
      stroke-dasharray="2 6" pathLength="6" transform="rotate(0)"/>
    <circle r="5" fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="10"
      stroke-dasharray="1 6" pathLength="6" transform="rotate(120)"/>
    <circle r="5" fill="none" stroke="tomato" stroke-width="10"
      stroke-dasharray="3 6" pathLength="6" transform="rotate(180)"/>
  </g>
</svg>



